# MSChart labels overlapping

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I've implemented pie chart using mschart. It's looks like this:

[image]

But when one of the part equals 0%, two labels are overlap and my pie chart looks like this:

[image]

How can i fix this? I'm use MSChart and can provide source code if this need.

Comment: you should try setting `Series` PieLabelStyle = "Outside"

Comment: The bug was fixed, but this was changed the design of the pie chart. This is not good. I don't know may be it's a feature:)